# Make multiple http requests in parallel

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a function which when called should make multiple http requests in parallel.
In the below code, I have an array of elements. I need to call patchElements method for each element and call updateData. When I run this, only the http call in updateData is made but if I console.log something in patchElements, it is getting printed.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

```
updateCriteria(id, values, elements) {
    return forkJoin(
      elements.map((el) => this.patchElements(rtId, values, el)),
      this.updateData(id, values)
    ).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        // do something
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        // do something
    ).subscribe();
}

patchElements(id, values, elements) {
    return this.http.patch(*url*);
}

updateData(id, updates) {
    return this.http.put(*url*);
}
```

Comment: I would like to point out that you should change your updateData end point so that it can take an array as parameter. That way you only do the expensive network roundtrip once rather than as many times as your elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forkJoin()` function from rxjs can only take in an array of promises and observables that complete, and one of the properties that you are giving it as an array. This should work:

```
updateCriteria(id, values, elements) {
    return forkJoin([
      ...elements.map((el) => this.patchElements(rtId, values, el)),
      this.updateData(id, values),
    ]).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        // do something
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        // do something
    ).subscribe();
}

patchElements(id, values, elements) {
    return this.http.patch(*url*);
}

updateData(id, updates) {
    return this.http.put(*url*);
}
```